# Signed multiplication result trim

Tags: vhdl

### What I have

I've two *signed* signals, `10b` length one of them and `2b` the other one.

```
signal R_S_R      : signed(9 downto 0);
signal prbs_sup_u : signed(1 downto 0);
```

Then I want to multiply them like:

```
R_S_E <= R_S_R * prbs_sup_u;
```

Storing the result into another `10b` signal.

### Why `10b` again

Because `prbs_sup_u` is 2b, and it'll only have [-1, 1] values (only those two). So, although result of multiplication is `12b`, I think (only if I'm not mistaken) I should be able to store the posible results of the operation in another `10b` signal.

### So your question is...

After doing the multiplication, I should be able to dispose of two of the bits from the `12b` result.

However, **which ones?** Since it's a signed signal, I don't know which one are disposable. Of course not the first one, since it's the sign, but after that...

Comment: Never 0? Then multiplication is the wrong approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use the `resize` operation to truncate unrequired MSBs (magnitude) like:

```
R_S_E <= resize(R_S_R * prbs_sup_u, R_S_E'length);
```

You can find the documentation in `numeric_std.resize`:

```
-- Id: R.1
function RESIZE (ARG: SIGNED; NEW_SIZE: NATURAL) return SIGNED;
-- Result subtype: SIGNED(NEW_SIZE-1 downto 0)
-- Result: Resizes the SIGNED vector ARG to the specified size.
--         To create a larger vector, the new [leftmost] bit positions
--         are filled with the sign bit (ARG'LEFT). When truncating,
--         the sign bit is retained along with the rightmost part.
```

If the `prbs_sup_u` can only have value 1 or -1, then you can also consider:

```
if prbs_sup_u = 1 then
    R_S_E <= R_S_R;
else  -- prbs_sup_u = -1 
    R_S_E <= - R_S_R;
end if;
```

The operation may then be more obvious, and the circuit will be smaller, since the implementation does not have to include handling of the unused 0 and -2 values.

Comment: Just a little question about `resize`, the "rightmost part" is the more significant one in signed codification? (So if I resize any signed signal it will take the most significant part?)

Comment: The "rightmost part" is the least significant one, thus as I wrote `resize` will truncate (remove) unrequired MSBs, e.g. "0001" becomes "001" if resized to 3 elements.

Comment: If the "rightmost part" is the least significant one, why is it kept? I'm getting confused..

Comment: The purpose of resize is usually to remove any unused bits, and keep the used bits.  The used bits are the rightmost part, as in my example, and the unused bits can be a number of bits in the leftmost part (except the sign), As in my example with "0001" and "001", then leftmost "0" is unused with respect to the value, just like in decimal where 0001 and 001 both represents the value 1.  For 2's complement the sign bit (leftmost) is kept, as said in the documentation.  One way to try it out is to run the simulator and do some `report` to get a feel for the results.